# Hibernate Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, maven

I upgraded my springboot application from 2.6.7 to 3.0.2. After the change, I am facing the below issue while running the maven build

```
[ERROR] SampleApplicationTest.contextLoads  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@74736e3e testClass = SampleApplicationTest, locations = [], classes = [SampleApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = ["test"], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@1a4cbcc6, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@5358c8fa, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@323fe1f5, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@9da1, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@407b41e6, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@a37796ef], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]

**Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: org/hibernate/type/descriptor/java/JavaTypeDescriptor
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/type/descriptor/java/JavaTypeDescriptor
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.JavaTypeDescriptor**
```

I tried cleaning my .m2 folder, also verified that both the files are present in the classpath.

```
org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class
org/hibernate/type/descriptor/java/JavaTypeDescriptor
```

Hibernate version used is 6.1.6.Final which is compactible with springboot version 3.0.2.

My Pom.xml in short

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.2</version>
  </parent>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>  
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <version>6.1.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
  <version>6.1.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

How can I resolve this NoClassDefFoundError issue ?

-Regards
Srikant Mantha

**Update to my issue:**
There is another version of JavaTypeDescriptor.class in my .m2 path which is needed for a different project. Its getting conflicted with my new project where I am trying to upgrade to springboot 3.0.2.

How can I exclude the unnecessary dependencies from .m2 which is not needed for my project ?

[image]

Comment: It would probably help to include your pom contents in the question. Relevant pieces of the pom only, please; entire pom files can be large and "noisy."

Comment: FYI, `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` already declares `hibernate-core` 6.1.6 as a dependency, so you don't need to specify the version in your pom. You can probably just leave out the reference to `hibernate-core` altogether, it's a transitive dependency.

Comment: @E-Riz: updated my post with latest issue.

Comment: For me after I'v remove dependency com.vladmihalcea, problem gone.

Comment: @HoliBoom: Yes, after replacing the depenency of 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.2</version>
        </dependency>

with 

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.hypersistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hypersistence-utils-hibernate-60</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>

resolved the issue